# Why is .indexof() returning -1; when the item exists in the given array? | Google Script

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, google-apps-script, google-sheets

-SheetData Variable is obtaining only the first 2 columns of the given range on the current worksheet.

-WeeksRow - on a seperate worksheet "Totals"; I have the starting week date of every week in the Year, eg: '01 January', '08 January', '15 January', etc. This Array (WeeksRow) grabs this row.

```
function ImportData(){
  var SheetData = [{}];
  var WeeksRow = [{}];

SheetData = sheet.getRange(4, 1, sheet.getDataRange().getLastRow()-4, 1).getValues();


  var CurrentSheetName = Utilities.formatDate(sheet.getRange("B2").getValue(),spreadsheet.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),"dd MMMM");

  var TotalsSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Totals");

  WeeksRow = TotalsSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, TotalsSheet.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues();

  WeeksRow = String(WeeksRow).split(",").map(function(s) {return s.trim();});

  var ColumnToSelect = WeeksRow.indexOf(CurrentSheetName);
  Logger.log(CurrentSheetName)
  Logger.log(WeeksRow)
  Logger.log(ColumnToSelect)
```

---

Log Output after execution is:

```
[19-11-04 20:26:31:457 EST] 22 January

[19-11-04 20:26:31:458 EST] [Week Starting:, 01 January, , , , , 08 January, , , , , 15 January, , , , , 22 January, , , , , 29 January, , , , , 05 February, , , , , 12 February, , , , , 19 February, , , , , 26 February, , , , , 05 March, , , , , 12 March, , , , , 19 March, , , , , 26 March, , , , , 02 April, , , , , 09 April, , , , , 16 April, , , , , 23 April, , , , , 30 April, , , , , 07 May, , , , , 14 May, , , , , 21 May, , , , , 28 May, , , , , 04 June, , , , , 11 June, , , , , 18 June, , , , , 25 June, , , , , 02 July, , , , , 09 July, , , , , 16 July, , , , , 23 July, , , , , 30 July, , , , , 06 August, , , , , 13 August, , , , , 20 August, , , , , 27 August, , , , , 03 September, , , , , 10 September, , , , , 17 September, , , , , 24 September, , , , , 01 October, , , , , 08 October, , , , , 15 October, , , , , 22 October, , , , , 29 October, , , , , 05 November, , , , , 12 November, , , , , 19 November, , , , , 26 November, , , , , 03 December, , , , , 10 December, , , , , 17 December, , , , , 24 December, , , , ]

[19-11-04 20:26:31:458 EST] -1.0
```

---

As you can see the Item I'm looking for is 01 January; it clearly exists in the Array in the second element; i'm trying to use .indexof()

So why is the `.indexof()` command returning `-1.0`?

I have also tried searching for "01 January" against every element in the arry and it cannot find it. using the following code:

```
var i=0;
  while(i <= WeeksRow.length){
    if (String( WeeksRow[i]) == "01 January"){
      Browser.msgBox("found at "+i);
      break;
    }else{
      i++;
    }
    if (i == WeeksRow.length){
     Browser.msgBox("not found") 
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please remove the prefix space of date in WeeksRow array (after splitting)

Comment: I tested your script and is working perfectly for what you want. Please share a copy of your Spreadsheet with all the private information removed. Additionally, could you try to replicate the issue in a different Spreadsheet and Script? May be is an issue specifically related with those your're working with.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's whitespace at the beginning of each element of `WeeksRow`, you need to strip this off before searching.

```
var WeeksRow = String(WeeksRow).split(",").map(function(s) {return s.trim();});
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar. I just noticed this too...strange why it does this; if you know why, that would help me understand this particular conundrum..

The way I have the row set up is, each Week date (01  January) for example, has 5 columns of data, so...01 January starts on Column A, then 07 January starts on Column G (5 rows after A). The way I have it showing is Rows A-F are Merged.

Comment: The issue must be with the code that's filling in the columns, it's passing it on the left with spaces.

Comment: I'm presently still encountering the issue, even with trimming off the extra white space.

Answer (score 0):

Try this version.  It's a little closer to working.

```
function ImportData(){
  var spreadsheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet=spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var SheetData = [];
  var WeeksRow = [];
  SheetData = sheet.getRange(4, 1,sheet.getLastRow()-4,1).getValues();
  var CurrentSheetName= Utilities.formatDate(new Date(sheet.getRange("B2").getValue()),spreadsheet.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),"dd MMMM");
  var TotalsSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Totals");
  WeeksRow = TotalsSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, TotalsSheet.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues()[0];
  var WeeksRow = String(WeeksRow).split(",");
  var ColumnToSelect = WeeksRow.indexOf(CurrentSheetName);
  Logger.log(CurrentSheetName)
  Logger.log(WeeksRow)
  Logger.log(ColumnToSelect)
}
```

Also you might want to read about [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Could you explain what the problem is, and what you changed to fix it?

Comment: Hi @Cooper. Your code still produces a -1.0 result. it's not finding ColumnToSelect inside the WeeksRow array; even though it exists.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know it can solve your condition or not:

```
  WeeksRow = TotalsSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, TotalsSheet.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues();

  WeeksRow=WeeksRow.toString();

  var lgth;
  do 
  {
    lgth = WeeksRow.length;
    WeeksRow = WeeksRow.replace(/, /g, ",");
  }
  while (WeeksRow.length < parseInt(lgth)); 
  WeeksRow = WeeksRow.split(",");
```